# How does Bit Masking Buffer Index Result in Wrap around

Tags: binary, embedded

Can someone explain how bit masking works in terms of a circular buffer index. Specifically   in the following code:

```
#define USART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 128     /* 2,4,8,16,32,64,128 or 256 bytes */
#define USART_RX_BUFFER_MASK ( USART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1 )


    ISR(USART_RX_vect)
    {
        unsigned char data;
        unsigned char tmphead;

        /* Read the received data */
        data = UDR0;
        /* Calculate buffer index */
        tmphead = ( USART_RxHead + 1 ) & USART_RX_BUFFER_MASK;
        USART_RxHead = tmphead;      /* Store new index */

        if ( tmphead == USART_RxTail )
        {
            /* ERROR! Receive buffer overflow */
        }

        USART_RxBuf[tmphead] = data; /* Store received data in buffer */
    }
```

I know the result of bit masking the index is that the index wraps around; my question is why? Also, why does the "USART_RX_BUFFER_SIZE" have to be a power of 2?

Thank you

Joe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand this, you have to understand some binary, and you have to understand binary operations.

As you probably know, everything in computers is stored in binary, sequences of ones and zeros. This means that any string of data in memory can be treated as number, theoretically. Since your code is usin `char`s, I will focus on them.

in C, `char`s are either signed or unsigned, it is important that you use unsigned for this. I won't get into two's complement representation, but suffice it to say that it would break if you used signed `char`s. A `char` is a single byte, and that is normally considered to be 8 bits, like so:

```
00000000 -> 0
00001001 -> 9
```

Basically each bit represents a power of two (I'm using MSB-first here), so the second number is `2^1 + 2^3 = 1 + 8 = 9`. So you can see how it can be used to index into an array.

Bitwise operations operate on the individual bits of some data. In this case, you are using binary **and** (`&`), and the act of applying binary **and** is called bit-masking.

```
data   - 00101100
mask   - 11110110
       ----------
result - 00101100
```

As you can see, the result has bits set to 1 only where both the `data` and `mask` has 1.

Now back to our binary representation. Since each bit is a power of two, a power of two in binary can be represented using a single 1 in amongst 0's.

```
01000000 - 64
```

And just like `1000 - 1 = 999`, `01000000 - 1 = 00111111`, where `00111111` is 63.

Using that we can find that when working out the next index, we perform the following operation:

```
(a + 1) & 00111111
```

if a is (for example) 10, then we get

```
(00001010 + 1) = 00001011 (11)
 00001011 & 00111111 = 00001011
```

So masking made no change, but in the case of 63:

```
(00111111 + 1) = 01000000 (64)
 01000000 & 00111111 = 00000000 (0)
```

So rather than trying to index into 64 (which is the 65th element, and therefore an error), you go back to the beginning.

This is why the buffer size has to be a power of two, if it wasn't then the mask wouldn't calculate properly and you would have to use modulo (`%`), or a comparison, rather than bit masking. This is important because bitwise operators are very fast, given that they are normally only a single instruction in most processors, and `&` would require very few cycles. A modulo may be a single instruction, but it would probably be integer division, and that is traditionally quite slow on most platforms. And a comparison would require several instructions, registers and at least 1 jump.

Comment: I suggest looking at more of the bitwise operators. Due to their nature, they can be implemented in very few cycles on a processor. Embedded programmers often need to squeeze performance out of a simple chip, so these tricks can help (like a << n being the same as a * (2*n), though compilers will often do this optimisation.)

Comment: I second the comment about modulo, we found on our micro it was taking something like 10-20x longer to do "a %= MODULUS" than to do if(a>b) a/=MODULUS;

Comment: ...I would further add that doing a normal compare is not so very inefficient in this case, we use that in our buffer code.

Answer (score -1):

JOhn writed:

> I second the comment about modulo, we found on our micro it was taking
>   something like 10-20x longer to do "a %= MODULUS" than to do if(a>b)
>   a/=MODULUS; – John U Aug 3 '12 at 17:01

But there is still division : a/=MODULUS and therefore effeciency is same as modulo operation, i assume ..